# Prime Knight travels through Prime Country

Tags: number-sequence, no-computers, chess

Prime Knight travels through Prime Country... Ride along and Document Details of his Journey

As this Prime Knight (only chess move allowed) journeys through Prime land, he makes a pit stop at every successive  prime site. No cell is ever revisited.

There are 64 of them..starting at 2 (cell A1) and ending at 313 (C8). The numbered cells shown in the picture are mandatory stops.

$List$ $of $64 $Prime $ $Numbers$

2,3,5,7, 11,13,17,19

23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53

59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89

97,101,103,107,109,113,127,131

137,139,149,151,163,167,173,179

181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227

229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269

271,277,281,283,293,307,311,313

[image]

You can get lost and miss the mandatory stops if you don’t take the right path.

Document the journey in chess notation

For example...A1, C2.......so on...ending at last pit stop at 313(cell C8).

Or present picture with all the journey stops.

Comment: Why prime numbers?  That's just a hassle...

Comment: He is prime knight...does not know other numbers..you can always number the primes 1 to 64..after you solve, you can substitute the primes

Comment: Uh, your list of primes is only 63 long, (it's the first 65 primes without 7 and 157) [Note: This was annoying as I just spent a while trying to crack it assuming it was meant to be the first 64 primes :(]

Comment: I am sorry, I missed 7 in the first row..editing now

Comment: 313...C8 is the final stop for the Knight.

Comment: Please work with the list provided..assume Knight goes from 151 to 163..163 to 167...173..till the end..the rest of all primes should be ok..thx for catching it

Comment: Why not just change 257 to 251 and 313 to 311 in the puzzle?

Comment: I have already created the solution based on the numbers given in the list..lot of things have to be changed which can create more problems..best thing is to stick with the list I have provided..jump from 151 to163..rest of it will be in order..

Comment: If you don't alter the puzzle I'd suggest making a note alongside "List of 64 Prime Numbers" to state 157 is missing.

Comment: Or, like, you could've not used prime numbers to begin with.

Comment: We are splitting hairs here.. admittedly I missed one..but the list gives you all the successive prime site Knight is going to visit..as far as puzzle is concerned, the Knight follows the sequence given..only missing 7 was an oversight which was quickly corrected.

Comment: For starters H8 = 31 and F7 = 37 which leaves 41 with two choices.

Comment: Right..will post more hints tomorrow

Comment: Is there only a single solution, or many?

Comment: For the given configuration and constrained mentioned, 63 step solution is unique .

Comment: @TheSimpliFire why is your step unique? how about 31 in H4?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No because otherwise H8 will never be revisited and 'left' again, since corners only have one entrance and exit move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the ball rolling with some initial thoughts...

Notation:

> Bold - Certain
>   Not Bold - Hints, like those in Sudokus

1.

> C2 must be 3 for 2 to reach 5

2.

> 107 must be F1 or F3 to link 103 to 109

3.

> 7 must be D3 or D5 to link 5 to 13

4.

> 11 must be E1, E3 or F4 to link 7 to 13

5.

> F2 and G2 must be 251 and 263 to reach 257 at H1

Grid after Step 1-5:

> [image]

Comment: Nice...looks more visually appealing..he is very tricky Knight